# Maximising precision in glsl

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-4

[Related to this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506628/why-does-varying-float-equality-test-fail-in-glsl)

I am having suffering due to lack of precision in the following function in glsl:

```
double LinearizeDepth(double depth)
{
  double z = depth * 2.0 - 1.0; // back to NDC
  return  (2.0 * near_plane * far_plane) / (far_plane + near_plane - z * (far_plane - near_plane));
}
```

I want to threshold on a depth value like so

`abs(linearised_depth - threshold_value) < epsilon` and my code works as expected when epsilon >= 0.5. I want to reduce epsilon to ~0.1. Are there any tricks to help with this?

Comment: Are `near_plane` and `far_plane` `float`? if so, you could try to cast them to `double`

Comment: I think this answer is doing what you what. Yet the expression seems shorter. You might want to try it and see if it gives better precision. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51137756/1754322

Comment: @tuket glsl has no equivalent to c/c++ type cast operators (see [GLSL - 5.1. Operators](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#operators)). Anyway you can construct a double from a float, e.g. `float f; double d = double(f);` (see [GLSL - 5.4. Constructors](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#constructors))

Comment: I think your  main issue is not the precision of the math here, but the precision of the underlying depth buffer where `depth` comes from. Using a reverse depth mapping + float depth buffer might help.

Comment: Reverse depth mapping?

Comment: my bet is your precision get lost between shader stages instead of the code you provided.... For more info and true linear depth see: [How to correctly linearize depth in OpenGL ES in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42515399/2521214)